# Using colons with such as

Tags: grammar

This paragraph is from a grammar book. However, I know that colons should not be used with "such as".

Is this an exception to the rule that I knew?

Sentences that begin with words that indicates portions, such as: percent, fraction, part, majority, some, all, none, remainder, etc., look at the noun of the prepositional phrase (object of the preposition) in order to determine whether or not to use a singular or plural verb.

Comment: To use  a comma there, it should be *such as **the following**:*. Worse by far is that if the colon should be there, everything after *etc.* most definitely should *not*. In the sentence, *etc.* (which shouldn't really be used anyway) ends the list items and that's where the sentence should stop. It can be easily fixed by simply not using a comma at all. Perhaps it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, that looks like a very incorrect use of the colon. What precedes the colon needs to be a complete sentence (according to some authoritative sources) and, in this case, it is not.

Even if the sentence before the colon is complete, the use of a colon is unnecessary when it is preceded by "such as", "including", or "for example". These phrases already tell the reader that a list follows. See [Colons](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaColons.htm).

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS) guide says *"... a colon is not normally used after namely, for example, and similar expressions; these are usually followed by a comma instead"*.

> Many writers assume—wrongly—that a colon is always needed before a series or a list. In fact, if a colon intervenes in what would otherwise constitute a grammatical sentence . . . there is a good chance it is being used inappropriately. A colon, for example, should not be used before a series that serves as the object of a verb. When in doubt, apply this test: to merit a colon, the words that introduce a series or list must themselves constitute a grammatically complete sentence. - CMoS

*"Do not use a colon (:) after one of these terms ["such as" and "including"]; they are meant to directly introduce the relevant examples."* - [Editing Tip: 'Such As' and 'Including'](https://www.aje.com/arc/editing-tip-such-and-including/).

Also, we don't use "etc." with "such as" or "for example". See this question in ELU.

[Is it correct that “etc.” can not be used together in a sentence with “for example” and “such as”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/is-it-correct-that-etc-can-not-be-used-together-in-a-sentence-with-for-examp)

*"And never use etc. at the end of a series that begins with "for example", "e.g.", "including", "such as", and the like, because these terms make "etc." redundant: they already imply that the writer could offer other examples."* - [All About etc](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/all-about-etc/).

Comment: that's bad. apparently this paragraph was taken from a grammar book. I thought I this sentence might be an exception to the rule that I knew.